# Two call methods and only the first call result is being saved in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have a class in C#, RandomVariableUniforme; This class has the following method: 
(Max and Min are properties to modify the fields max and min)

```
public double runif(ref Random randomNumber)
{
    double number;

    number = Min + randomNumber.NextDouble() * (Max - Min);
    Console.Write("number = {0,6:F3}    ", number);
    return number;
}
```

and in the main file i have the following: (where A[i] and A[j] are objects of the above class with different max and min, saved in a array.)

```
int n = 5;
double[] x = new double[n];
double[] y = new double[n];
Random randomNumber = new Random();
for (int cont = 0; cont < n; cont++)
{
    x[cont] = A[i].runif(ref randomNumber);
    y[cont] = A[j].runif(ref randomNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("\nx[cont] = {0,6:F3}   y[cont] = {0,6:F3}", x[cont],   y[cont]);
}//end for
```

however while the method is generating the pseudo random numbers correctly the program is 
saving only the first call. The output is the following: (where number is the number generated by the method and the number that should be saved by the corresponding vector below the

```
number = 509,986    number = 470,079
x[cont] = 509,986   y[cont] = 509,986
number = 507,614    number = 418,733
x[cont] = 507,614   y[cont] = 507,614
number = 432,070    number = 463,316
x[cont] = 432,070   y[cont] = 432,070
number = 446,716    number = 476,604
x[cont] = 446,716   y[cont] = 446,716
number = 440,344    number = 459,617
x[cont] = 440,344   y[cont] = 440,344
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "saving". All I see is random numbes being printed.

Comment: Saving in the array x and y in the index cont.

Comment: Note that there's no need to pass your `Random` instance using `ref`.  It's a reference type, so passing it by value is only copying the reference, which is just fine in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format string is referencing the first argument twice.

Change this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nx[cont] = {0,6:F3}   y[cont] = {0,6:F3}", x[cont], y[cont]);
```

To:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nx[cont] = {0,6:F3}   y[cont] = {1,6:F3}", x[cont], y[cont]);
                                                     ^
```

Also, as a side note, you don't need the `ref` in `ref Random randomNumber`, in your case it does nothing.